# I have 5 users and I want each of them to see different content when the login

Tags: javascript, php, html

the user logins in with one of 5 emails:

- red@mydomain.com
- blue@mydomain.com
- black@mydomain.com
- green@mydomain.com
- purple@mydomain.com

once they are logged in the application assigns the following team name to each email

- red@mydomain.com = Red
- blue@mydomain.com = Blue
- black@mydomain.com = Black
- green@mydomain.com = Green
- purple@mydomain.com = Purple

The objectives and motivations for each team are stored in a help menu and each team has different objectives and motivations,  and I am using for example red_objectives_page.html to redirect the user to see the relevant objectives.   The teams are not allowed to see each other's objectives and motivations

at the moment it is defaulting to "access_denied.html"

Here is the javascript from my script.js file:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var objectivesButton = document.getElementById('objectives-button');
if (objectivesButton) {
objectivesButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
var team = "<?php echo $team; ?>"; 

// Redirect users based on their team
if (team === "Red") {
window.location.href = 'red_objectives_page.html'; // Redirect user to the Red objectives
} else if (team === "Black") {
window.location.href = 'black_objectives_page.html'; // Redirect user to the Black objectives  
} else if (team === "Green") {
window.location.href = 'green_objectives_page.html'; // Redirect user to the Green objectives 
} else if (team === "Blue") {
window.location.href = 'blue_objectives_page.html'; // Redirect user to the Blue objectives 
} else if (team === "Purple") {
window.location.href = 'purple_objectives_page.html'; // Redirect user to the Purple obj   
} else {
window.location.href = 'access_denied.html'; // Redirect user access denied page if unknown    
}
});
}
});
// event listener for "Motivations" button
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var motivationsButton = document.getElementById('motivations-button'); 
if (motivationsButton) {
motivationsButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
var team = "<?php echo $team; ?>"; // Team information from server-side

// Redirect users based on their team
if (team === "Red") {
window.location.href = 'red_motivations_page.html'; // Redirect user to the Red motivations 
} else if (team === "Black") {
window.location.href = 'black_motivations_page.html'; // Redirect user Black motivations
} else if (team === "Green") {
window.location.href = 'green_motivations_page.html'; // Redirect user Green motivations
} else if (team === "Blue") {
window.location.href = 'blue_motivations_page.html'; // Redirect user Blue motivations
} else if (team === "Purple") {
window.location.href = 'purple_motivations_page.html'; // Redirect user Purple motivations 
} else {
window.location.href = 'access_denied.html'; // Redirect to access denied page unknown teams
}
});
}
});
```

At the moment it defaults to the access_denied but I know that the Session is storing the Team as when I use another part of the application the database is correctly assigning team based on the email

Comment: Is `$team` exactly equal to the values in your if statements? For instance it might have a non-visible(like a space) character in the string that throws off the comparison, eg `" Red"` vs `"Red"` or might have different character case. Check the source of the page as you should be able to see if your php rendered the js code for setting your variable correctly.

Comment: What is your question? Since you pass $team variable from PHP, you can also pass objectives and motivations to avoid these ugly IFs. Do you have a session check to deny access to the other pages for unauthorized users? Can I directly open blue_objectives_page.html even I am in red team?

Comment: @fela desired functionality is that teams can only access their own page of objectives and motivations.  I was not sure how to do it hence the ugly 'IF" statements.  My question is how to have each team only see their relevant objectives and motivations based on their team

Comment: "_from my script.js file_" PHP won't work in `.js` files unless you told your webserver

Answer (score 0):

There are several options

1. You should have a single pages generated in PHP for motivations and objectives. Each of them should verify session and you can display the relevant content. In JS, you have always buttons to /motivations.php and /objectives.php, which check the user's team and displays the correct content or an access denied error.

**Simple solution concept:**

Since you are using PHP, you do not need additional JS for such functionality.
When the user logs in, you can redirect them to welcome.php, which verifies the user and displays two links `<a href="motivations.php">` and `<a href="objectives.php">`. When the motivations link is clicked, the user is redirected to motivations.php, which verifies the user's and displays the relevant content.

2. if you need different URLs for each team, you need to check in PHP in each file whether the user of the current session has access to it.

**Simple solution concept:**

When the user logs in, you can redirect them to welcome.php, which verifies the user and displays two links relevant for the team i.e. `<a href="blue_motivations.php">` and `<a href="blue_objectives.php">`. The correct link you can generate in PHP or pass variables to the view. When the motivations link is clicked, the user is redirected to blue_motivations.php, which still need to verify the user before outputting the content.